# Get the client hostname in intranet with linux environment using javaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, linux, hostname

I looking for a way to return the hostname of the client, I have seen several posts that say it's impossible to get the machine name, but I think it's possible to have it on the intranet.

It's possible ?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry not in js but, In php you could use  gethostbyaddr() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php :

```
  $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  echo $hostname;
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers do not provide an API for JavaScript to access the hostname of the client.

On an Intranet, you could run a web service which performs a reverse DNS look up based on the IP address the request came from and then call that web service via Ajax.

Comment: No … and the specifics would depend on your choice of language anyway.

Comment: I found a solution with php, look to my answer.

Thank you.